# UWP Use Shy Header for ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I basically copied code from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869003) and then changed variables to mine. I have also copied the files under the folder ExpressionBuilder.

And inside the [ShyHeader.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/blob/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ShyHeader/ShyHeader.xaml.cs), there is such line of code:

```
var scrollViewer = gridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
```

So I tried same thing for my `ListView` but it says undefined:

```
SongsListView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>()
```

So I put a `ScrollViewer` around the `SongsListView` and use that. But I fail to get it working for my project. The header is neither sticky above nor shy. It just gets scrolled normally. Can anyone help me debug it?

SongsListView is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml).

SongsListView is used [here in HeaderedPlaylistControl](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml).

ShyHeader is implement [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml.cs) at the bottom.

HeaderPlaylistControl is used in [AlbumPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/AlbumPage.xaml), [MyFavoritesPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MyFavoritesPage.xaml) and [PlaylistsPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/PlaylistsPage.xaml).

Comment: `GetFirstDescendantOfType` may the extension method for `GridView`.

Comment: What about using my own `ScrollViewer`? Why does it not work? I even used `ScrollHeader` and set its `Mode` to "Sticky". However the header is still not sticky. This happens before I try to implement Shy Header.

Comment: Please check [`VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs`](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/blob/master/SamplesCommon/SamplesCommon/VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs) class, it is base on the VisualTreehHelper.

Comment: As you know each  ListView contains `ScrollViewer` that used to sroll the content.

Comment: For using this method  your could copy this extension to your project, and this is extension class, it will available for all `DependencyObject` .

Comment: Please check your ListView  if you have implement ListView header in xaml.

Comment: You need remove packed ScrollViewer from `SongsListView`. otherwise, you will get the wrong Srollviewer when called `GetFirstDescendantOfType`  method.

Comment: I just noticed that problem and used the builtin one. But still not working.  Code has also been updated.@NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Well, I will check the new version.

Comment: Please remove [`<UserControl>`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml#L16)  from `HeaderPlaylistControl`, and call `SetShyHeadermet` in PlaylistInfoGrid loaded event handler.

Comment: Does removal work for you? I need that because I need visual state manager for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200054/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-lone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I tried same thing for my ListView but it says undefined

This is extension method for DependencyObject. You could find it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/blob/master/SamplesCommon/SamplesCommon/VisualTreeHelperExtensions.cs) and copy it to you project.

> So I put a ScrollViewer around the SongsListView and use that. But I fail to get it working for my project.

I checked your code, you need call [`SetShyHeadermet`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml.cs#L118) method when
`PlaylistInfoGrid` loaded.

```
private void PlaylistInfoGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetShyHeader();
}
```